# How to share content on WhatsApp from iOS

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I would like to share one Url link and some text message into WhatsApp from my application. How can i share content?

I got this code for only text

```
NSString * msg = @"Trueman India Magazine";
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
```

but how i share my url link in WhatsApp?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the link as a string like `msg`?

Comment: No i will not tryed because in simulater whats app is not installed. any possibility to install whats app in simulater?

Comment: Why are you even asking if you haven't bothered trying yet? Please do research by trying yourself before asking. No you can't install whatsapp on the simulator you will need a physical device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the plain link inside the text, e.g.:

```
NSString * msg = @"Trueman India Magazine http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com";
```

The link will be generated/tappable after sending it to someone

Comment: The 'Check this out' is an example on text to share

Comment: Well the way it seems is you are telling them to check out stackoverflow. Please add proper code to show you example anyone can turn around and say check this out that is a terrible answer.

Comment: OK I improved the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: That's better I have removed my -1

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem with this whatsapp api with url strings, especially when they contained a query string with several fields, e.g. http://example.com/foo?bar=foo&foo=bar.
When opening the app I found the message text would be empty.

The solution was to properly percent escape the string using the CFString functions.
See the apple documentation here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes

But for anyone else with this issue here is my solution in full:

```
CFStringRef originalURLString = (__bridge CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://example.com/foo?bar=foo&foo=bar"];
CFStringRef preprocessedURLString = CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, originalURLString, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSString *urlString = (__bridge NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, preprocessedURLString, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
NSString *whatsAppURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", urlString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:whatsAppURLString]];
```

- Note the use of the characters to be escaped in the CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes function.

Comment: all operation works well like : +, -, *, /.    But when i use % then WhatsAppURLString returns (null)

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using simple jquery. here is the article link http://www.stepblogging.com/how-to-share-web-article-on-whatsapp-using-jquery/

and you can check demo on your smart phone [Demo Link](http://demo.stepblogging.com/whatsapp-share-jquery/)